# trouble validating a php textarea

Tags: php, validation

So I have a form as below:

```
 <form id="order" method="POST" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
 <div>
        Description:<br> <textarea rows="15" cols="40" name="description" id="description" maxlength="300" form="order_form" value="<?php if (isset($description)) {echo $description;}?>"></textarea>
    </div>
```

then for my validation I have

```
 if (!empty($_POST['description'])) {
$description = $_POST['description'];
} else {
$error_messages[] = "You did not enter a product description <br />";
}
```

only problem now is that once I submit the form, it always end up returning the message that i did not enter a product description.

Any clue as to what I am doing wrong here?

From my unserstanding this is what is being suggested:

```
Description:<br> <textarea rows="15" cols="40" name="description" id="description" maxlength="300" form="order_form"><?php if (isset($description)) {echo $description;}?></textarea>
```

Comment: In regards to validation, I'd recommend adding something like `&& trim($_POST['description']) != ''` to your if statement as well, to prevent getting any blank descriptions where someone has just held down space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to put the value of the textarea inside the  element, not in a value attribute

```
<textarea>some value</textarea>
```

Comment: Ok, so ive done what you've suggested, and edited the post to show my work, but i am still getting the same result.

Comment: well I see that you have the attribute form="order_form" that doesn't match with your form ID <form id="order"